# Getting process name winapi

Tags: winapi

I have the problem , I can't get names of every process, some process show normal name but another return . How can I get the name of such process ? But the id is ok.
May I did something wrond , I am testing this on Windows 8.1 
Here is the code .

```
      DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
   unsigned int i;

   //This returns a list of handles to processes running on the system as an array.
   if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) ) {
      return 0;
   }
   // Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.  
   cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

   // Display the name and process identifier for each process.  
   for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ ) {
      if( aProcesses[i] != 0 ) {
         DisplayProcessNameAndID( aProcesses[i] ); 
      }
   }
   void DisplayProcessNameAndID( DWORD processID )
{
   TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");

   // Get a handle to the process.  
   HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
      PROCESS_VM_READ,
      FALSE, processID );

   // Get the process name.  
   if (NULL != hProcess )
   {
      HMODULE hMod;
      DWORD cbNeeded;

      //Given a handle to a process, this returns all the modules running within the process.
      //The first module is the executable running the process,
      //and subsequent handles describe DLLs loaded into the process.
      if ( EnumProcessModules( hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), &cbNeeded) )
      {
         //This function returns the short name for a module,
         //typically the file name portion of the EXE or DLL
         GetModuleBaseName( hProcess, hMod, szProcessName,
            sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR) );
      }
   }

   // Display the process name and identifier.
char buffer[400];
   sprintf_s(buffer,"Text:%s, PID : %u", szProcessName, processID );
   MessageBox(mainWinH,buffer, "Ok", MB_OK);

   //close the process handle
   CloseHandle( hProcess );
}
```

Comment: You will inevitable run into one or more processes that don't let you peek at them because you don't have enough rights.  Including the "System" process which is a place-holder for ring0 code.  Just move on, nothing to see there.

Comment: You do not need to call `EnumProcessModules()` to call `GetModuleBaseName()`, set the 2nd parameter to 0 instead. Also have a look at `GetProcessImageFileName()` and `QueryFullProcessImageName()`, which do not require as many rights on `OpenProcess()` as `GetModuleBaseName()` does.